# Can i blur the text using php or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to blur the text(like name, city , etc) for unpaid users of my site, So they cannot see the text that i want to restrict.

Is there any method in PHP or JQuery to blur the text in the way  that user cannot see the actual information even from the Web Inspector or Web Console.

I have check the jquery plugin named **Foggy** its working but user can see the text in web inspector. So Please suggest me if any way in PHP that i can blur the text from my server side.

Any hint will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why not showing the text is not on option? You can just show Restricted information, etc. instead of bluring the text?

Comment: use canvas......! or wrap them in some span etc element if the text is inline and you can set the z-index of it to -1.

Comment: Just don't display the information  ._.

Comment: Just wrap those text in span and add css display: none and @Phiter ernandes  is also right

Comment: I want to enticed  the user for payment thats why i need to blur the text .

Comment: So replace the text in php with for example `****`. Anything you send to the browser can be read by the visitor so js and css solutions will not meet your requirements by definition. By the way, blurring / hiding information might not be the best way to entice users for payment, you could also show a limited complete introduction or number of articles per month.

Comment: Yeah jeroen is right, you can put some fake text and blur it.

Comment: Yeah @jeroen and Phiter, i think this is the last option that i can use , put some fake text and blur it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As javascript is client side, surely someone could figure out how to unblur this. I am sure many libraries exist to do what you need, but if you really want the information hidden server side would be the way forward.

Similarly I am sure you could achieve this with CSS, but the information will still be accessible.

Have you considered changing the result from say `London` to `Lxxxxx` or even `XXXXXX`. You could achieve this with `strlen` and `substr` (if you wanted to show the first letter).

Another possibility is to use a conditional to see if you should show it or not and then show say the first letter and then a generic image with blur. So maybe somehting like:

```
echo '<span>'.substr($name,0,1).'<img src="blur.jpg"></span>';
```

**Update**

Maybe the best way is to both change the text and to blur it, please see the following:

```
<style>
.blurit {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
</style>
<?php
    $str = "United Kingdom";
    echo '<span class="blurit">' . strtoupper(substr($str,0,1)).preg_replace("/[a-z]/", "x",substr($str, 1)) . '</span>';
?>
```

Comment: Yes i have check with changing the result from say London to Lxxxxx.
But its not good looking

Comment: @PrinceGautam glad I could be of service. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

no, at least not as (HTML) text because you will always be able to see the source of your HTML.

the only possibility would be to render the text as image(s) using some PHP graphic library ([GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) or similar) on the serverside. But this would be very bad practice in terms of clean web design.
edit: *plus you would need to take care about the image of the text needing the same space as the actual text and so on..*

Comment: _very bad practice_ ? How ? Why ?

Comment: @RayonDabre because it's bad practice to display text as image(s) in html.

Comment: Nobody does that for fun... In such situations, you will have to as there is no other way around.. I doubt it is a BAD PRACTICE...

Comment: @RayonDabre well, if you really want it this way, you'll have to do it. but this still keeps it a bad practice in terms of web design and right usage of html.

Comment: I would love to have a reference which would justify your statement. Good luck ;)

Comment: He he.. That link does not address certain issues like the one OP has..Will you recommend using text over image in place of CAPTCHA ?

Comment: @RayonDabre i don't even answer this troll question. difference is that a captcha is usually around 4 to 10 letters long, and is NOT the text of the webpage which is considered to be the main content. imagine the text being 10.000 letters long - you will have to render it dynamically into an image and make sure it (more or less) exactly needs the same space like the real text does. plus instead of around 5kB your image needs around 100 or even 200kB of diskspace and bandwidth. yes, that's what i would call **BAD PRACTICE** in terms of web design.

Comment: If it is needed to be an image then it is needed.. It is a bad practice if used where it is not needed or could be avoided. The reason captcha is displayed as image is to avoid reading it as a normal text. The same case is here.. I suggest you to read above ref as it never says you MUST,it says you SHOULD...

Comment: @RayonDabre yeah, and it's bad practice cause it can be avoided. see alexP's answer for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could show a "fake text" and load the real text via Ajax.

HTML

```
<div id="box">
  That's the fake text
</div>
```

CSS

```
#box{
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}

.nofilter{
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px) !important;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#btn-nofilter').on('click', function(){
  $box = $('#box');  
  $box.text('Thats\' the real text.'); //GET TEXT WITH A AJAX REQUEST
  $box.addClass('nofilter');
});
```

But anyway: The blur effect is created using CSS3 and not JavaScript.

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rd7er3x7/)

Comment: i like this idea. you would not necessarily need ajax to show the real text tho. doing it with PHP would be enough since the user has to log in to see the real text anyways. with a little research you could randomly replace letters with other letters of the same font with the same length. so the space needed keeps exactly the same.

Comment: yes, but for me the blurred text is quite a bit longer than the unblurred text.

Comment: Yes, because of the Apostroph. You have to exclude special chars like " ", ",", "'", ...

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
jQuery('.blurry-text').css('color','transparent').css('text-shadow','0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5)').text('XXXXX');
```

Comment: He would be able to see the text via WEB Inspector, as OP said.

Comment: @Gunjan,   yes Phiter is right, this can be access from web-inspector or console